# Wordpress blockquote removes `<br>` tag

Tags: php, wp-autop, line-breaks

So I have a quote in my page template and I would like to give the user the opportunity to add line breaks whenever they desire to do so.

I wanted the blockquote to have an extra `<p>` tag inside the `<blockquote>` tag so I could style it better.

The problem I'm having now is that the `<br />` tags are being removed. While using the `wpautop()` function they should stay.

Here is what I did:

```
$matched = preg_match("~(?<=<blockquote>)([\s\S]+?)(?=</blockquote>)~",
wpautop($child->post_content), $found); // find the quote in the content with regEx

$found = current($found);
$replace   = "<blockquote><p>".$found."</p></blockquote>";// add the <p> tag
$newphrase = str_replace($found, $replace, $found);

$clearQuote = preg_replace("~<blockquote>([\s\S]+?)</blockquote>~", '', 
wpautop($child->post_content, true)); // use wpautop to keep the <p> tag
```

Can anyone see why the `<br>` tag is being removed or do I need to add something else?

I came to realize that I don't think it has something to do with the `wpautop()` function.

The variable I use it in is used to filter it out of `the_content()`.
So `$clearQuote` uses the found quote and deletes it from `the_content()` where `$quoteFound` uses the found value and doesn't use `wpautop()`.
So it must be something else.

I added the `wpautop()` function to the `$matched` variable so it would add a `<p>` tag to where the user break the line. This way there isn't really a line break but the output is the same.

Comment: Where is this quote being entered? One purpose of `wpautop` is to turn a new line entered into a textarea into HTML line breaks without the user having to enter them themselves.

Comment: The quote is being placed within the regular `post_content` editor.

Comment: Then you shouldn't need to do anything. Users can already enter line breaks into quotes with Shift+Enter. Blockquotes have paragraphs in them added by `wpautop`, so why are you adding a paragraph around the entire contents of the blockquote? What if there's two paragraphs already?

Comment: Well the problem is that I need to have `<p>` tags within the `<blockquote>` tags.

Comment: They get added by WordPress, you shouldn't need to do anything.

Comment: Please see my updated answer!

Comment: You haven't really answered why you're doing this. WordPress supports line breaks and paragraphs in blockquotes on its own, so I'm not clear on what problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Well the problem is that `<blockquote>` doesn't contain `<p>` tags (well at least not in my installation) so I needed to add them.

Comment: In a fresh install of WordPress if you use the blockquote control in the editor and write some text, the text inside the blockquote will be wrapped in a paragraph/paragraphs when output. I notice that you're using the `post_content` property directly. This has not had wpautop applied, so will not have them.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Yeah haven't updated it yet but indeed whilst adding the `wpautop()` function `the_content()` contains `<p>` tags